# Does ESRI ArcGIS API for JavaScript support vector tiles with fill-extrusion Style Property?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, 3d, vector-tiles

ESRI ArcGIS API For JavaScript’s support GL JSON Stylesheets/Vector Tiles that use fill-extrusion property?
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#fill-extrusion

{
"id": "building-3d",
"type": "fill-extrusion",
"source": "openmaptiles",
"source-layer": "building",
"paint": {
"fill-extrusion-color": "hsl(39, 41%, 86%)",
"fill-extrusion-height": {
"property": "render_height",
"type": "identity"
},
"fill-extrusion-base": {
"property": "render_min_height",
"type": "identity"
},
"fill-extrusion-opacity": 0.6
},
"filter": [
"all",
[
"!has",
"hide_3d"

Trying to show 3D Buildings from either MapBox or OpenMapTiles/MapTiler

Comment: What happens when you try to use it in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: It's hard enough adding a non ESRI vector tile source but I got data showing but when I tilt I am not seeing 3D buildings

Comment: Please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.